# How to mock `with` key word using minimoc in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How to mock `with` key word statement like this?

```
 with io.open("sample.file", 'r') as input:
      for line in input:
          #do something
```

I know how to mock `io.open` by minimock in this way:

```
mock_string = io.BytesIO('mock_string')
minimock.mock('io.open', returns=mock_string)
```

But the `mock_string` is closed, as the statement reached the end.

UPDATE:

```
mock_string = io.BytesIO('mock_string')
minimock.mock('io.open', returns=mock_string)
with io.open("sample.file", 'r') as input:
      for line in input:
          #do something
mock_string.read() #this mock_string is closed by with.
```

How can I stop `with` closing the stream by mocking `with` statement.

Comment: Why would you wan't to prevent the `close` operation? It's the purpose of using `with` here and should probably also be called when testing...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of avoiding the `close` operation, a better way to mock this would be using a callable that creates a new `BytesIO` instance for every `io.open` call.

According to the minimock docs, the code snipped below might be an alternative:

```
mock_string = lambda fname, fmode: io.BytesIO('mock_string')
minimock.mock('io.open', returns_func=mock_string)
```